# About Particle Property: Why there are two sources in the scene generating particles?

Tags: particles

I am learning Blender's particle functions.

In this case I only give one object particle property, but in the animation there are two source generating particles.
I wonder why.

Blend file link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tEC99lIUSO-izhbP0RH6Hi9HtJ0Wg6OU/view?usp=share_link

Video demo on Youtube:
https://youtu.be/qdsELHQWMSM

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The *second source* appears to be the Suzanne.001 origin, when no vertices are available to the particle domain.

You also have the same problem if I set particle start=1.

I think you may have a bug to report. When I open your file and display the console I see a message Can't create particles with the current modifier stack, disable destructive modifiers probably because before frame 12 the object with boolean actually has zero vertices, which is also true when the errant particles start at around frame 40.

For now you can set your emission end-frame to frame 40 as a workaround (when no vertices are left *outside* Cube.001).

I've had a similar bug with fluid simulation (no particles in a domain for some frames causes render problems).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will report it to the development community.

Comment: Sorry for asking non relative question of this post. But I am studying particle and fluid system of Blender to achieve an effect simulating dirt being washed away(dirt integration by fluid force) by running water in a pipe. I am not expecting a solution but tips or ideas of what the steps might be. What my thought is to make two simulation and combine them in timeline. Fisrt is this particles blown away by wind, and second is of cause the water running. But it is hard to make this idea realistic since the two sims are not interactive. I fumble around many tutorials, but couldn't find a way.

Comment: @QuanLee -- I see you wisely submited a separate question to blender_stackexchange to get discussion.  A search for "[fluid-simulation] [particles]" will help you somewhat.